# The result of printing an uint64_t array

Tags: c

I have this small piece of code:

```
uint64_t test[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
printf("test value: %llu\n", test);
```

I try to print the `test` array, and it gives me this number:

```
test value: 140732916721552
```

Can someone explain this and how an uint64_t array works? Thank you

Comment: `test` is not a `uint64_t`, but a `uint64_t[]`.

Comment: i already clarified it's an `uint64_t` array

Comment: yes, and `%llu` is the print specifier for a  `uint64_t`, not a `uint64_t[]`
You want to print the individual **elements**.

Comment: No I have no intention of printing individual elements. I need an explanation

Comment: What **do** you intend to print? How many format specifiers are in `printf("test value: %llu\n", test);`?  Just what do you think the variable `test` means in that code???

Comment: I have no intention of printing anything, I want an explanation why `140732916721552` is the result of printing `test` (which is an uint64_t *)

Comment: If you want to print all the elements in the array, you need a loop to iterate over them.  In the loop you can print them one by one.

Comment: @klg its the "address" of the array interpreted as a long unsigned integer

Comment: *I have no intention of printing anything* Huh?!?!  Just what do you think `printf()` **does**?!?!

Comment: @Raildex  Pedantically it's undefined behavior because `%llu` is not a proper format specifier for an address.  But yeah, it's probably just that address interpreted as an `unsigned long long`.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I hesitated to say it's UB, but I decided not to.

Answer (score 2):

In your code

```
uint64_t test[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
printf("test value: %llu\n", test);
```

`%llu` tells `printf` that it shall print a `long long unsigned` integer. The `test` part of the `printf` statement pass a **pointer to the first element of the array** to `printf`. In other words, there is a mismatch between what you are passing (a pointer) and what you tell `printf` to print (long long unsigned).

In C such a mismatch leads to "undefined behavior". So in general it's not possible to say what will be printed. Any print out will be legal from a C standard point of view. No print out would also be legal.  A program crash would be legal. Anything... would be legal.

It's impossible to say what goes on in general. On a specific system, it's possible to dig into the low level things and figure out what is going on. On my system the printed value corresponds to the address of the first array element interpreted as a long long unsigned integer. But don't rely on that. Other systems may do something completely different.

The code below shows how to correctly print the address of the array and the array elements.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

int main(void) 
{
    uint64_t test[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    
    // Print the address where the array is located
    printf("Address of test value is %p\n", (void*)test);
    
    // Print the values of the array elements
    size_t sz = sizeof test / sizeof test[0];
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sz; ++i)
      printf("test[%zu] is %" PRIu64 "\n", i, test[i]);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Output (note: address may differ in every invocation):

```
Address of test value is 0x7ffc4ace5730
test[0] is 1
test[1] is 2
test[2] is 3
test[3] is 4
test[4] is 5
```

Answer (score 0):

When you define an array like this in C, what you are actually doing is storing each of these values sequentially on the stack as separate `uint64_t`s. The value assigned to the `test` identifier is then a pointer to the first of these values, a `uint64_t*` rather than a `uint64_t`. When you print `test`, you are printing the pointer rather than any of the elements, i.e. the memory address of the first element in your array.

The `[]` notation is equivalent to

```
*(test + i)
```

i.e. it dereferences a pointer to the `i`th element.

Comment: *C does not have an array type per se.* [**WHAT?!?!?!**](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p20):  "An array type describes a contiguously allocated nonempty set of objects with a particular member object type. ..."

Comment: C **has** arrays. It's just that they decay to pointers when passed to functions

Comment: I've never really counted arrays as "proper" types, I suppose because they cannot be used in function parameter declarations but yes they probably do count as types technically. The point I was trying to make by this is that they are not the first-class citizens that arrays typically are in higher-level languages.

Comment: Sentence *"The value assigned to the test identifier is then a pointer to the first of these values, a uint64_t* rather than a uint64_t."* is objectively wrong. Conversion to pointer happens on function call, not when test array is created.

Comment: "The value assigned to the `test` identifier is then a pointer ...". That's not how it works at all. The pointer comes from *converting* the array designated by the identifier `test`.

Comment: And what high level language passes arrays by value, exactly? Array parameter passing is rather one of the few cases where C behaves exactly like higher level languages.